# Creating discounts that are stackable

Tags: forms, settings

I'm creating a stacked discount setup page and I am stuck on a screen. I do not know how do I visualise the setup when the input can be numerical or 'all' items at any point of time.

Imagine you have a single product: Book

- Buyer receive 10% on first three (3) books bought, or buyer receive 10% on all books bought
- Buyer receive 10% on first three (3) books bought, and 20% on all subsequent books bought
- Buyer receive 10% on first three (3) books bought, 20% on next three (3) books, and 50% on all subsequent books bought.
- User can add more discount tiers as needed.

This will eventually be translated into cart where the buyer can see the discounts.
In the discount setup page, how would you visualise this?

[image: my mockup but it does not make sense]

Comment: I'm curious how the system works. How many tiers can user create? Can user choose whether discount will apply to "first books", "next books" or "subsequent books"? I'd also love to know benefits of stackable discounts vs regular discounts. Is this just a marketing trick and is it more effective? Because looking from users' POV I'd say that this system is too complicated and I'd prefer having a regular discount rather then calculating how many books should I buy to get discount X.

Comment: @fakermaker currently, there is no limit of tiers, and the discount should apply in an order from 'first books', 'next books' then 'subsequent books'.

without going into much detail - think of it like its a B2B platform. The discount can increase with each tier, or it can just remain one flat tier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is super rough. And I hope I understand the question. But what if you asked the user to select between entering a number of books or all remaining books?

So, after adding a discount, there could be a radio button selection below the percentage that could allow the user to select between entering the number of books or applying the discount to all remaining books.

If the user clicks all remaining books, I expect they couldn't add another tier.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackexchange. I used your answer as the solution to my project. :) Thank you!